# Dynamic drop down menu in CakePHP throws [ReferenceError] in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I am a beginner to CakePHP and coding in general. I am trying to create a pair of dynamic dropdown menus where the selection in the 2nd is dependant on what is chosen in the 1st. I have followed a number of guides but i dont seem to be getting good results. Recently I followed the answer to the question here: [CakePHP re-populate list box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642872/cakephp-re-populate-list-box/) but all i get is a **`"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`** when using google chrome.

I am using CakePHP 2.5.4 with the database given in the example

My Users controller:

```
<?php

function beforeFilter()//executed before any controller action logic
{
            $this->Security->enabled = false;


    }
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 * @property SessionComponent $Session
 */
class UsersController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $countries = $this->User->Country->find('list');
        $cities = $this->User->City->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('countries', 'cities'));
        // populate selects with options
    $this->set('countries', $this->User->Country->find('list'));
    $this->set('cities', $this->User->City->find('list'));

    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
        }
        $countries = $this->User->Country->find('list');
        $cities = $this->User->City->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('countries', 'cities'));
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

View/users/add.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('country_id');
echo $this->Form->input('city_id');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

$this->Js->get('#UserCountryId')->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(
        array('controller' => 'countries', 'action' => 'get_cities'),
            array(
                'update' => '#UserCityId',
                'async' => true,
                'method' => 'post',
                'type' => 'json',
                'dataExpression' => true,
                'evalScripts' => true,
                'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true)),
        )
    )
);
```

Countries Controller

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Countries Controller
 *
 * @property Country $Country
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 * @property SessionComponent $Session
 */
class CountriesController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');

public function get_cities(){
    Configure::write('debug', 1);
    $cities = array();
    if(isset($this->request->query['data']['User']['country_id'])){
        $cities = $this->Country->City->find('list', array(
                  'conditions' => array('City.country_id' => $this->request->query['data']['User']['country_id'])
        ));
    }
    $this->set('cities', $cities);
}
/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Country->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('countries', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Country->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid country'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Country.' . $this->Country->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('country', $this->Country->find('first', $options));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Country->create();
            if ($this->Country->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The country has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The country could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Country->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid country'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Country->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The country has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The country could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Country.' . $this->Country->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Country->find('first', $options);
        }
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Country->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Country->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid country'));
        }
        $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Country->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The country has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The country could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

View/cities/get_cities.ctp

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($cities)){
        foreach ($cities as $id => $name) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
<?php           
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you add jquery library e.g. in your layout?

Comment: @marian0 sorry i am a complete noob, could you elaborate for me please? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't include jquery library on your site. You can do this two ways: download a file and put into `webroot/js` directory or link it from [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery).

If you choose first solution, you have to visit [jQuery official page](http://jquery.com/download/) and download current version of library. Then move file to your project under `APP/webroot/js` path. It's good practice to change name of file to `jquery.js` without information about version. Last thing is open your layout file which sholud be located in `APP/View/Layouts/your_layout_file.ctp`. If you don't have custom layout it will be called `default.ctp`. Last step is finding `<head>` tag and putting following line:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>
```

Or if you don't change name, you have to pass there whole name of file as param without extension.

If you want link library from external sources like Google CDN you just need to get url to jQuery from site, and put following line in your layout file:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'); ?>
```

More about `HtmlHelper` and `script()` method you can read in [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script).